# Matching two different Values simultaniously in a column of Matrix

Tags: r

Please help me in finding column index where two different values present at the same time.

```
  library(combinat)
  y = c(4.7378092,0.8278563,2.7577482,0.7261934,3.0687797)
  m=combn(y,3)
       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
[1,] 4.7378092 4.7378092 4.7378092 4.7378092 4.737809 4.7378092 0.8278563 0.8278563 0.8278563 2.7577482
[2,] 0.8278563 0.8278563 0.8278563 2.7577482 2.757748 0.7261934 2.7577482 2.7577482 0.7261934 0.7261934
[3,] 2.7577482 0.7261934 3.0687797 0.7261934 3.068780 3.0687797 0.7261934 3.0687797 3.0687797 3.0687797
```

I am using `which(m==y[1&2],arr.ind=TRUE)` that returns only index of mentioned values of `y` variable, but I want column Index of given matrix where both values present of vector `y`, i.e column # 1,2 and 3.In return there should be a vector that contain values (1,2,3).

Comment: The question is not clear. can you add the expected result? Do you want to get the index of columns that share some values?

Comment: yes, the index of column that contain all mentioned values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
which(apply(m,2, function(x) all(y[1:2] %in% x)))

# [1] 1 2 3

m[,apply(m,2, function(x) all(y[1:2] %in% x))]

#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 4.7378092 4.7378092 4.7378092
# [2,] 0.8278563 0.8278563 0.8278563
# [3,] 2.7577482 0.7261934 3.0687797
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It works for first two values but what for the 1st and 3rd value together `y[1,3]` ?

Comment: I got that it `y[c(1,3)]`